# SFINAE to detect the explicitness of a CTAD deduction guide

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, template-meta-programming, ctad

Little-known feature of CTAD (class template argument deduction) in C++17: you can mark user-defined deduction guides as `explicit`.
([Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/5nzxjefTT))

```
template<class T> struct A { A(int); };           A(int) -> A<int>;
template<class T> struct B { B(int); };  explicit B(int) -> B<int>;

A<int> a = 1;  // OK, constructor of A<int> is implicit
B<int> b = 1;  // OK, constructor of B<int> is implicit

auto a = A(1);  // OK, deduction guide of A exists
auto b = B(1);  // OK, deduction guide of B exists

A a = 1;  // OK, deduction guide of A is non-explicit
B b = 1;  // ERROR!! deduction guide of B is explicit
```

So, class templates `A` and `B` have observably different behavior.
I'd like to write a unit test that `static_assert`s that one of my templates behaves like `B`, not like `A`.

```
static_assert(!has_properly_explicit_deduction_guide_v<A>);
static_assert(has_properly_explicit_deduction_guide_v<B>);
```

Is this possible in C++17 and/or C++20 and/or "C++future"?

Comment: Well, I was exploring the potential for `new` (to save you time: it won't work) and found some more bugs: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=101988 and https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51547 . Fun!

Answer (score 3):

No.

You can't check declarations, so you can't check the validity of `A a = 1;` or `B b = 1;`

And class template argument deduction isn't valid in any other copy-initialization contexts. So while you can check "implicitly convertible" by seeing if the expression `[](To){}(from)` is valid, you cannot check "implicitly class-template-argument-deducible" by seeing if the expression `[](A){}(1)` is valid, since you cannot just write `A` there.

The only thing that you can check is whether `A(1)` is valid or not, but that is direct initialization, and so would not be able to validate `explicit`ness.

Comment: Any additional thoughts on https://godbolt.org/z/P3bdvYh17 ? NTTPs are another context where CTAD is valid; but (1) this would work only for NTTP-friendly types, which obviously doesn't help in _general_, and (2) there seems to be implementation divergence here.

Comment: @Quuxplusone You can do that [much simpler](https://godbolt.org/z/G1Y9eMdT9). gcc allows explicit deduction guides in this context though. And yes, this isn't a general solution.

Comment: .. which is now [#101833](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=101883).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, per [[dcl.type.class.deduct]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.class.deduct), a placeholder for a deduced class type can appear in:

- the initializing declaration of a variable;
- a *new-expression*;
- explicit type conversion (functional notation); or
- a non-type template parameter [NTTP].

The first of these is not SFINAE-able (either classically or in a `requires` clause), since it is a declaration and not an expression; the next two invoke direct-initialization, not copy-initialization; and the last only works for structural types with `constexpr` constructors (although this isn't particularly clear from the Standard).

wrt. future direction, back in 2018 Mike Spertus was angling for CTAD on function template arguments: [Improving function templates with Class Template Argument Deduction](http://wg21.link/p1167), [How to make Terse Notation soar with Class Template Argument Deduction](http://wg21.link/p1168). There hasn't been much movement on this since then, but perhaps it could be resurrected.